# Errno 111 Connection refused: Issue with rendering PDF with xhtml2pdf in Django on a Linux server with static files images

Tags: django, linux, deployment, apache2, xhtml2pdf

I've successfully deployed my Django project on a Linux server, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to print PDF reports. The images located in the static folder are causing errors during the rendering process.

`<img class="logo" src="http://{{host}}/static/logo_1.jpeg">`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Doas.png)

It's worth noting that I can access these images through their respective URLs, but I'm getting a connection refused error with xhtml2pdf.

I'm curious if there might be some Apache2 configuration settings that I may have overlooked that could be causing this connection issue in the context of xhtml2pdf. Any insights or guidance on potential Apache2 configurations would be greatly appreciated.

My goal is to determine if there's any permission or configuration issue with Django URLs that I might have overlooked. What doesn't make much sense to me is that I can view the images through the URL, but they can't be rendered in a PDF. Does this library use a different type of connection when importing images for PDF rendering?